# Adding same second Form2 to same project but same style as template vb net

Tags: vb.net, borderless

I have made some borderless Form1 in my solution, now I want AboutBox will have same design and also I need more 2,3 Forms but same style.
If I click "add new item" or "existing" it add the main Form like default Visual Basic has :'(
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, all the design of the form is stored in the `Form.Designer.vb`! file.
You can simply copy the properties you wish to apply to the added forms and past it in their designer accordingly.
[Check image below to see the designer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtMxn.png)

1. Modify the form as you wish them to be.
2. Once done, save the changes
3. Open the designer and copy all the codes
4. Add another form.
5. Open its designer and paste all codes
6. Change the name of the form
7. The form will be a duplicate of the previous one and you can adapt your changes.

Comment: I have the designer file in PC folder BUT nit in solution and when i drag and drop it from folder in project IT IS NOWHERE in .sln solution :(

Comment: I Tried to copy it but it shows me many errors and soem strange window message, so i undo and deleted form and did again, else i couldnt open it, the Form1 has many codes and Form2 = aboutbox can not have it so i would need all modify one step by step, this coudl takes me lot of time to do, Is there some sample way? thx

Comment: The only thing you'll need to change is the form's name. No simpler way, at least if you know exactly the properties you wish to replicate for the other form, you can copy only those properties.

Comment: How do i mark your answer as answer? im new here sorry cant see any option to "award" you this question, thx I started making copy and deleted all content i dont needed and save as 2nd telmplate then just copy as you said the designed code and it works :-)

Comment: Good it works for you ;) to mark it as answer, you just need to click the 'tick' on the top left corner of the answer, under the vote ratings.

Comment: ok thanks :) ALSO I CAN NOT ASK anymore any question, DO YOU KNOW WHY PLS? :'(